# Tiled Tiff decoding error by 3rd party readers

Tags: image, tiff

I am trying to write tiled tiff images with libTiff in c++. I have no problem in encoding and decoding the image in my program, but 3rd party reader softwares shows they have problem decoding. For example:

1. In windows, my tiff cannot be previewed/opened by windows photo viewer;
2. With QGIS, most of the time when I zoom-in/out, it warns "TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed" yet sometimes it handles the same area and level with no problem reported.

For debugging, I wrote the same image in png, let libvips convert it to tiled tiff and no reader complaints about that one. I read the tiff6.0 specification and wrote a program to check the IFDs and they are identical. The two files are [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yOEIrkuz4Oab0fRiThHWni2iQ1jQnA84/view?usp=sharing).

What have I done wrong? Is there any generic image format checking tools that I may use to solve these issues?

Much appreciated.

Comment: I had a quick look with tiffinfo and the only difference I could see was the size of the JPEG tables --- yours are much smaller, for some reason. I would join the libtiff mailing list and ask there. https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/tiff

Comment: @jcupitt Thanks, I think that is the problem. I switched to libjpeg for the compression step and everything goes right.